# jQuery duplicate item inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<div id="container">
     <div class='label-item-text drag' data-type='text'>
         <div>Right click on me and check the HTML of the duplicated</div>
     </div>
</div>
```

And I'm trying to duplicate the items inside `#container`. Unfortunately is not working as I expect.

> A) My code duplicates all the items inside, when actually I have only selected one
>
> B) I can't duplicate properly

The code that duplicates all items is the following.

```
$('#container').append($dragRightClick.parent().html());
```

Well, the `parent()` of `$dragRightClick` is the `#container`, so I understand the reason why it duplicate all the items...

**What I want to duplicate** is only the div inside the `#container`, that means:

```
<div class='label-item-text drag' data-type='text'>
    <div>Right click on me and check the HTML of the duplicated</div>
</div>
```

But what I've got so far is only:

```
<div>Right click on me and check the HTML of the duplicated</div>
```

The following code outputs the above code:

```
console.log("Clone: " + $dragRightClick.clone().html());
console.log("HTML: " + $dragRightClick.html());
```

You can check the full problem **[in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o6s7cyzf/)**.

Comment: +1 for explaining the question in a well formatted and lucid manner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**outerHTML**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.outerHTML) for this purpose:

Replace:

```
$('#container').append($dragRightClick.parent().html());
```

with:

```
$('#container').append($dragRightClick[0].outerHTML);
```

### [UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/o6s7cyzf/1/)

You can also use this jquery plugin written for `outerHTML`:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/outerhtml-jquery-plugin/

Comment: Well, I've heard about outerHTML and it started working on firefox 11..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html - But maybe, that's not a big problem in nowadays?

Comment: `outerHTML` is javascript property of element

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
$('#container').append($dragRightClick.clone());
```

instead of this :

```
$('#container').append($dragRightClick.parent().html());
```

See [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o6s7cyzf/4/)